How to set planner_id in Simple Commander API
I hope to use Simple Commander API.
So, I read https://docs.nav2.org/commander_api/index.html#id1.
In this document, there is the following description.

getPath(start, goal, planner_id=’‘, use_start=False)

I have two question.
Q.1: The default value of planner_id is ’‘.
How does this API behave in this case?
Q.2: Now, I used the following planner for navigation.

NavfnPlanner
DWB

What value should I set as planner_id?


How does this API behave in this case?

It uses the default planner, i.e. the only planner when there's only one planner in the planner server. If you have multiple planners, you must populate it.

What value should I set as planner_id?

With the planner's name, not just the algorithm. Go into your configuration file and fine what you called the planner (default is "GridBased"). The planner_id is the planner, the controller_id is the controller.

Thank you for your answer. I understood.
